# Nested Dictionary Python with fantasy football data

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to run my own statistics model to try and get an edge in my fantasy football league, and I'm having troubles creating my data structure of dictionaries. My data looks like this.

```
Player  Team    G   Att Yard    TD  Target  Rec Yard    TD  FFPts   FFpts/G
Adrian Peterson MIN 1   18  93  2   4   4   18  1   29.1    29.1
Reggie Bush DET 1   21  90  0   8   4   101 1   25.1    25.1
LeSean McCoy    PHI 1   31  184 1   1   1   5   0   24.9    24.9
Joique Bell DET 1   6   25  2   6   5   67  0   21.2    21.2
Jamaal Charles  KC  1   16  77  1   6   3   23  0   16.0    16.0
Shane Vereen    NE  1   14  101 0   10  7   58  0   15.9    15.9
```

and I have files for each week of the season.

```
{'Adrian Peterson': 
    {'week1.txt':
       {'Team':'MIN', 'G':'1','Att':'18'....}
    }
    {'week2.txt':
       {'Team':'MIN', 'G':'1','Att':'20'....}
    }
}
```

However, when I run my code it overwrites each week, and I can't figure out why.

Code:

```
import os

def makeDict():
    directory = os.listdir('.')
    print directory
    playerDict = {}
    for item in directory:
        if item != 'bayes.py' and item !='.DS_Store':
            f = open(item)
            headers = f.readline().split('\t')
            for line in f:
                    stats = line.replace('\n','').split('\t')
                    statDict = {}
                    weekDict = {}
                    for i,stat in enumerate(stats):
                        if i ==0:
                            player = stat
                        else:
                            statDict[headers[i]] = stat
                        if i == len(stats)-1:
                            weekDict[item] = statDict
                            playerDict[player] = weekDict

    return playerDict

print makeDict()
```

It ends up that the dictionary only holds the information from the last file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest looking into [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for getting your files out of the directory. As well as breaking that large function into several smaller ones and having one function to call all of them.

Comment: If you're going to be processing tabular data like this you should check out [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org); for example, you could compute yards/attempt from a file by `df = pd.read_csv("ff.dat", sep="\t"); df["Yards/Attempt"] = df["Yard"]/df["Att"]`, etc, and you can `concat` multiple files easily.  More time spent crunching numbers to figure out who to pick up off the waiver wire and less time spent writing boilerplate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the way you have structured your output dictionary is wrong. If `Adrian Peterson` 's stats are going to be in several files, and you wish to aggregate them under one key (i.e., his name) then `playerDict[player_name]` should be a list.

So change your code to do the following:

1. `from collections import defaultdict`
2. `playerDict = defaultdict(list)`
3. `playerDict[player].append(weekDict)` instead of `playerDict[player] = weekDict`

I duplicated `Adrian Peterson`'s data across different files, made the above changes to your code and this is what I see:

```
{
    'AdrianPeterson': [
        {
            'data': {
                'FFPts': '29.1',
                'Yard': '18',
                'Target': '4',
                'G': '1',
                'Att': '188',
                'Team': 'MIN',
                'Rec': '4',
                'TD': '1',
                'FFpts/G\n': '29.1'
            }
        },
        {
            'data2': {
                'FFPts': '29.1',
                'Yard': '18',
                'Target': '4',
                'G': '1',
                'Att': '188',
                'Team': 'MIN',
                'Rec': '4',
                'TD': '1',
                'FFpts/G\n': '29.1'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `data` and `data2` were the name of my files. In your case, it would be `week1.txt` and `week2.txt`